# How to use convolutional neural network on binary image using Keras?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to train a cnn model for ocr using keras. I preprocessed the images by converting to grayscale, removing noise and then converting it to binary, as binary images work better in ocr. But the problem I am getting is that binary image has 2 dimensions and no channel dimension and conv2d in keras(well any conv layer in general) require 3 dimensions. So what should I do to add a dimension but keep image binary? I am using cv2 for image processing so please tell solutions using that preferably. Also tell me whether I am right that using binary image dataset is better for ocr.

Comment: change the dnn architecture to only use one channel. Or add redudant channels, but this will make your model unnecessarily complex.

Comment: @Micka but the conv2d layer of keras requires 3 input dimensions. How can I change that? As for adding redundant channel how to add that?

Comment: according to the docs: `"When using this layer as the first layer in a model, provide the keyword argument input_shape (tuple of integers, does not include the batch axis), e.g. input_shape=(128, 128, 3) for 128x128 RGB pictures in data_format="channels_last"."` So I think you could use `input_shape=(height,width,1)` for your grayscale or binary data? Sorry, from my side it is only theoretical. And I don't know how to duplicate channels or sth. in python.

Comment: @Micka I am using binary, not grayscale

Comment: yes, but it will be used as grayscale. The important thing is, that it is only 1 channel. That's the 1 in `input_shape=(height,width,1)`

Comment: @Micka  grayscale and binary is not same. grayscale has pixel values 0 to 255 and a single channel ie monochrome image. binary has just 1 and 0 and no channels. when shape of the image array is printed, it give (width,breadth) and not (width,breadth,1) as in grayscale

Comment: I know about differences in grayscale and binary, but your neural network will have floating point precision, so it will make no difference. In addition, most cv libraries like opencv don't care whether you use 0 and 1 or for example 0 and 1-to-255 as your binary represenation and typicaly they save the masks in 8 bit anyways, even if there are only 2 different values present. The thing is, that you don't want to use 3 channels and I think I've shown you the part of the documentation about how to use only 1 channel. Did you try it?

Comment: @Micka so should i now convert image to binary and keep it grayscale? btw i amd using cv2 threshold meth with otsu thresholding. also the input shape that u are saying is not working for binary. It gives error that input array is 3 dimensional(including batches) instead of 4d.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my solution. I used numpy function numpy.expand_dims() to add empty dimension. so it became (width,height,1). Here is what I did:-

```
img = np.expand_dims(img,axis=2)
```

Comment: How you converted RGB to binary image? I need to convert my images for OCR. And how Binary images are better for OCR? There are some methods they used threshold value for binary conversion but how we can guess that threshold value?

Answer (score 0):

You cam use numpy.repeat to copy the first dim into 3 dim to get 3d image

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).